# Javascript - Replace lots of if statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, refactoring, code-cleanup

I have a a couple of different radio buttons which return an ethnicity and a gender. The script runs inside an internal application so rather than returning "boy", "girl" or "both" I get back 7707330, 7707333, and 7707336. Similar from the ethnicity radio button.

I then need to validate data based on the combonation of ethnicity and gender. This was a pretty simple task but I have ended up with 15 if statements! It all works as it should, but there must be a cleaner solution?

```
function test(radioResults) {
    var1 = radioResults[0].toString();
    var2 = radioResults[1].toString();

    var roll = parseFloat(parent.roll);

    if (var2 == '7707330') {
        gender = 'boy';
    }
    if (var2 == '7707333') {
        gender = 'girl';
    }
    if (var2 == '7707336') {
        gender = 'both';
    }

    if (var1 == '7707341') {
        maori(gender);
    }
    if (var1 == '7707344') {
        pasifika(gender);
    }
    if (var1 == '7707347') {
        all(gender);
    }
}

function maori(gender) {
    //Maori 
    if (gender == 'boy') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getMBoys);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
    if (gender == 'girl') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getMGirls);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
    if (gender == 'both') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getTotalM);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
}

function pasifika(gender) {
    //Pasifika
    if (gender == 'boy') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getPBoys);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
    if (gender == 'girl') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getPGirls);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
    if (gender == 'both') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getTotalP);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
}

function all(gender) {
    //All
    if (gender == 'boy') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getBoys);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
    if (gender == 'girl') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getGirls);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
    if (gender == 'both') {
        ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getTotalRoll);
        validation(ethnicity);
    }
}

function validation(ethnicity) {

    percent = ethnicity * 5 / 100;

    if (ethnicity - percent > roll || (ethnicity + percent < roll)) {
        parent.document.getElementById('CF_7784443').value = "FAIL";
    } else {
        parent.document.getElementById('CF_7784443').value = "PASS";
    }
}
```

How would I go about cleaning this up?

Comment: FYI, there is a new Stack Exchange site specifically for Code Reviews... http://codereview.stackexchange.com Just a heads up :)

Comment: Was unaware of that, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is to your taste, but it seems like a cleaner solution to me.  Lay out all the mappings separately first.  Then resolve the mappings to the correct property of *parent*.  Then invoke *validation*, just once, for the property you've retrieved.  Here's a sketch:

```
// map var1 and var2 to gender and ethnicity
var genderMap = { "7707330" : "boy", "7707333": "girl", "7707336": "both" };
var ethnicityMap = { "7707341": "maori", "7707344": "pasifica", "7707347": "all" };

// map gender and ethnicity to the correct property of "parent"
var props = 
    { "boy": 
        {
            "maori": "getMBoys", "pacifica": "getPBoys", "all": "getBoys"
        },
        "girl": 
        {   
            "maori": "getMGirls", "pacifica": "getPGirls", "all": "getGirls"
        },
        "all":
        {   
            "maori": "getTotalM", "pacifica": "getTotalP", "all": "getTotalRoll"
        }
    };

// get the correct property    
var prop = props[genderMap[var1]][ethnicityMap[var2]];

// run the validation
validation(parseFloat(parent[prop]));
```

Comment: Oh nice... That is more what I was looking for. Let me just see if I can get my head around it ;)

Comment: `var prop = props[genderMap[var1]][ethnicityMap[var2]];` is giving me an undefined error... I assume that var1 and var2 can stay how they originally were?

Comment: @user1011926 Yes... I just noticed a typo on the second line, I misspelled **ethnicityMap** ...

Comment: Yeah I also picked up and corrected that, wasn't the issue though sadly `'undefined' is null or not an object`

Comment: Ok, there were actually two typos in the same word ("enthicity" or something)... now I'm able to test with *var var1 = "7707330", var2 = "7707341";**, which makes prop = *getMBoys* (I can't test the last line as I don't know what *parent* is).

Comment: Intreasting, when I set var1/2 to the same values as you it does in fact work correctly. Which is odd because it holds the exact same value in the radioResults array. I should have made it clear at the start of what var1 and 2 are. Have updated the first post.

Answer (score 1):

Use `switch` may help

```
switch (var2) {  
   case '7707330': gender = 'boy'; break;  
   case '7707333': gender = 'girl'; break;  
   case '7707336': gender = 'both'; break;
   default: gender = 'not boy or girl here?';
}
```

Document [here in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Edit: shrink newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I'd code it like this. Some people may suggest `switch` statements, but I've truthfully never used them in my code, as they increase the line count without impacting readability:

```
function foo() {
  var func;

  if (var1 == '7707330') {
    func = maori;
  } else if (var1 == '7707344') {
    func = pasifika;
  } else if (var1 == '7707347') {
    func = all;
  }

  if (var2 == '7707330') {
    func('boy');
  } else if (var2 == '7707333') {
    func('girl');
  } else if (var2 == '7707336'):
    func('both');
  }
}

function maori(gender) {
  //Maori 
  if (gender == 'boy') {
    ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getMBoys);
  } else if (gender == 'girl') {
    ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getMGirls);
  } else if (gender == 'both') {
    ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getTotalM);
  }

  validation(ethnicity);
}

function pasifika(gender) {
  //Pasifika
  if (gender == 'boy') {
    ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getPBoys);
  } else if (gender == 'girl') {
    ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getPGirls);
  } else if (gender == 'both') {
    ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getTotalP);
  }

  validation(ethnicity);
}

function all(gender) {
  //All
  if (gender == 'boy') {
    ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getBoys);
  } else if (gender == 'girl') {
    ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getGirls);
  } else if (gender == 'both') {
    ethnicity = parseFloat(parent.getTotalRoll);
  }

  validation(ethnicity);
}

function validation(ethnicity) {
  var percent = ethnicity * 5 / 100;

  if (ethnicity - percent > roll || (ethnicity + percent < roll)) {
    parent.document.getElementById('CF_7784443').value = "FAIL";
  } else {
    parent.document.getElementById('CF_7784443').value = "PASS";
  }
}
```

Comment: Good thing about this, as you said is readability isn't effected.

Comment: just on the border to not use switch, if they would have been 4+, then a switch is undoubtedly better in all ways (including performance, but for 3- `if+if elses` are better). However, I am not upvoting this

Comment: @ajax333221: Can you justify your performance benefit? I'm pretty sure most JavaScript engines optimize `switch` statements to `if...else` blocks in the end.

Answer (score -1):

well, in terms of clean code you could exchage your if's for Switch statements, here is a description:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

well that is the best substitution you can get. of course your code is also valid.